# Data from server is not coming in spinner in android?

Tags: android, mysql, android-spinner

I am trying to get server data into my spinner , but when i tried with this code , i am not getting anything, its not showing any data in spinner.
here is my Home.java file:

```
   public class Home extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener, AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    private Spinner countrySpinner, locationSpinner, citySpinner;
    private TextView cityCodeTextView;
    private Button submitButton;
    private ArrayList<String> country_list, location_list, city_list;
    private JSONArray result;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        countrySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(Country);
        //citySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(City);
        //locationSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Location);
        countrySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        country_list = new ArrayList<String>();
        //location_list = new ArrayList<String>();
        // city_list = new ArrayList<String>();

        getData();
    }
    private void getData(){
        StringRequest
                stringRequest = new StringRequest(Config.DATA_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        JSONObject j = null;
                        try {
                            Log.d("Test",response);
                            j = new JSONObject(response);

                            //Storing the Array of JSON String to our JSON Array
                            result = j.getJSONArray(Config.JSON_ARRAY);

                            //Calling method getStudents to get the students from the JSON Array
                            getCountry(result);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });
                RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        //Adding request to the queue
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    private void   getCountry(JSONArray  jsonArrayCountry){
        //Traversing through all the items in the json array
        List<Country> countries = new ArrayList<>();

        try {

            String country_name, country_code;
            JSONObject countries_object;


            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArrayCountry.length(); i++) {
                countries_object = jsonArrayCountry.getJSONObject(i);
                country_code = countries_object.getString("id");
                country_name = countries_object.getString("country");
                countries.add(new Country(country_code, country_name));
            }
            ArrayAdapter countryAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, countries);
            countrySpinner.setAdapter(countryAdapter);
            countrySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("Home", e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
        }



    }

    //Method to get student name of a particular position

    //Doing the same with this method as we did with getName()


    //Doing the same with this method as we did with getName()



    //this method will execute when we pic an item from the spinner
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        //Setting the values to textviews for a selected item
        //textViewName.setText(getName(position));
        //textViewCourse.setText(getCourse(position));
        //textViewSession.setText(getSession(position));
    }

    //When no item is selected this method would execute
    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
       // textViewName.setText("");
      //  textViewCourse.setText("");
        //textViewSession.setText("");
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    }
}
```

this is congig.java file:

```
public class Config {
    //JSON URL
    public static final String DATA_URL = "http://..../get_country.php";


    //JSON array name
    public static final String JSON_ARRAY = "result";
}
```

this is my json:

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "country": "UAE"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "country": "UK"
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "country": "SAUDI ARABIA"
  },
  {
    "id": "4",
    "country": "OMAN"
  },
  {
    "id": "5",
    "country": "BAHRAIN"
  }
]
```

i am not getting any error in logcat...i dont know why its not showing??

Comment: did you debugged you code ? what did you find out ?

Comment: no, ok will try  it

Comment: its not taking values it shows null in response

Comment: but when i run url in browser, its showing data

Comment: try to write ArrayAdapter countryAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, countries);
        countrySpinner.setAdapter(countryAdapter);  After the for loop

Comment: well if it's showing null in response that should throw nullpointer exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your Attached JSON your JSON Array don't have **any name** and you are trying to parse like

```
result = j.getJSONArray(Config.JSON_ARRAY); // Config.JSON_ARRAY = "results";
```

Your parsing seems to be incorrect.

you have to parse JSON array like this -

```
JSONArray result = new JSONArray(response);
```

Also remove

```
j = new JSONObject(response);
```

Comment: if i remove that n put urs code then it gives me red line on this line==  result = json.getJSONArray(Config.JSON_ARRAY);
in config.JSON_ARRAY

Comment: I am not getting what you are trying to say. Did you removed result = j.getJSONArray(Config.JSON_ARRAY); and j = new JSONObject(response); Check my updated answer

Comment: i gt the answer finally..thx urs code is working...only 1 line code i need to change

Answer (score 0):

Hi Can you try like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArrayCountry.length(); i++) {
           countries_object = jsonArrayCountry.getJSONObject(i);
           country_code = countries_object.getString("id");
           country_name = countries_object.getString("country");
           countries.add(new Country(country_code, country_name));
         }
ArrayAdapter countryAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, countries);
countrySpinner.setAdapter(countryAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you working with API First step is to check if API work Properly or not for that purpose you can use  **REST_CLIENT**  and **POSTMAN** 
Chekc -https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en

Put your URL , Header you want than check if response is perfect or not
If response  is correct than you can move to android side

I suggest you to use Gson Liabrary for parsing gson - https://stackoverflow.com/a/41616005/4741746

And you will get ArrayList directly that you need to set for Spinner

[image]

In the Responce section you will get your json than at android side parse it using Gson Lib      **BEST OF LUCK**

put this dependencies in app build.gradle file

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
} 




public class Responce implements Serializable {

    @SerializedName("result")
    public ArrayList<Data>  result;

    public class Data implements Serializable {

     /*{
       "id": "1",
       "country": "UAE"
     },*/
    @SerializedName("country")
    public String  country;

    @SerializedName("id")
    public String  id;
    }
}
```

Slightly change your response this is proper way to do this

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "country": "UAE"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "country": "UK"
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "country": "SAUDI ARABIA"
        },
        {
            "id": "4",
            "country": "OMAN"
        },
        {
            "id": "5",
            "country": "BAHRAIN"
        }
    ]
}
```

And now you can access it like

```
             @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {


                  Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
                  Responce movie = gson.fromJson(response, Responce.class);
                  ArrayList<Data>  mCountryList=movie.result;

                }
            }
```

Second Way But not proper way

```
@Override
   public void onResponse(String response) {


    try {
                    ArrayList<String> mStrings = new ArrayList<>();
                    JSONArray myArray = new JSONArray(response);
                    for(int i=0 ;i< myArray.length();i++){
                        JSONObject mObject = (JSONObject) myArray.get(i);
                        String id=  mObject.getString("id");
                        String country=  mObject.getString("country");
                        mStrings.add(country);
                    }
                    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, mStrings); //selected item will look like a spinner set from XML
                    spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
                }catch (Exception e){

                }
      }
  }
```

Comment: Now Print  responce and Log.d("Test",responce)   above j = new JSONObject(response);  this line and show me did you get that response in android side

Comment: but nt in spinner

Comment: Now what you have to do is just get that data in  Class form like  -http://stackoverflow.com/a/41218155/4741746

Comment: sorry, but tht is bit confusing..can u tell me with my code

Comment: SEEMS LIKE NOTHING IS WORKING FR ME :(

Comment: hi, i will updated my question again , plz see it..must b some issue, y m nt getting any thin in spinner

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133861/discussion-between-z-al-and-sushant-gosavi).

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to check if the json is parsed correctly. For this, put a `Log` inside the for loop where you are getting the country code and name.

if the JSON that you posted is the same as you got from `Log.d("Test",response);` , then you need to change 
From:

```
j = new JSONObject(response);
 //Storing the Array of JSON String to our JSON Array 
result = j.getJSONArray(Config.JSON_ARRAY);`
```

To:
`result = new JSONArray(response);`

Or else, if the response is like `{result:[...]}` , Then you are correct, you will get the json parsed.

Next, if you got the correct values inside the for loop Log, then the issue is with your Adapter. For simplify, use a custom adapter extending the `BaseAdapter` instead of ArrayAdapter.

Comment: i am getiing response is like {result:[...]}..i think i have a problem with adapter..can u code it

Comment: hi, can u tell me the correct way for that,, i m already getting the json response but its nt coming in spinner

Comment: This is an experiment. Leave the code as it is now, and override the `toString()` function of the Class 'Country' to return countryName only. Check it.

Answer (score 0):

Add

`adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);`

before setAdapter